# History Points in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a knockout web app. What I am trying to achieve in the app is to have a history stack so when on mobile if the user clicks back button I don't load the previous page but the previous state of the app.

The previous state could be that user was adding an order but he closed that screen. Now I want that if the user clicks the back button then I take him to that screen.

After searching online I saw that *html5* has something like *pushState* and *popstate*. I just want some suggestions if that is the best way to achieve that? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: `pushState` and `popState` are part of the History API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and are in fact the only means to achieve that. However, it has nothing to do with Knockout as it doesn't provide out-of-the-box support for routing. Another JS frameworks (like Angular) may provide better support in this field.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://pagerjs.com/